# how do I change my bash_profile to read and expose all the func() defined in some script files I have already?

Tags: bash

I have a few `.sh` here and there with 
some
`func()` defined in them
I want to change my `bash_profile` to read all of them and expose to my bash shell

Comment: I don't quite understand from your question, where you are stuck. Is it how to organize functions into a library of files, or about how to include them? The latter is called _sourcing_ and done by `. /path/to/your/file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that no harmful code is called within your `.sh`. Ideally, it should only include functions. Then you can `source` the file.

A simple test.sh I made:

```
$ cat ./test.sh
function test_source() {
   echo "** Called with $1"
}
```

and sourcing/invoking:

```
$ . test.sh
$ test_source asd
** Called with asd
```

So once you have tested this, you can add it to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` by sourcing it there:

```
if [ -f "/path/to/your/dotsh.sh" ] ; then
    source "/path/to/your/dotsh.sh"
fi
```

Logout, login (or open a new terminal) and the functions should be available to you

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the directory which contains those files to your PATH.
You can get this done automatically at every login by specifying it inside your `~/.profile`, like so:

```
# assuming $HOME/.bin contains your .sh files
if [ -d "$HOME/.bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Then, set your files as executable (`chmod +x /path/to/file`) and invoke them as regular shell commands. You may use parameters to specify which function to call, in this way:

```
case "$1" in
"func1")
    func1
    ;;
"func2")
    func2
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: I think this will add the folder to the path but it will not expose the functions within those files